# Nginx rewrite by map with parameters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite with map as

```
/oldpage?f=regist      -> /signup
/oldpage?f=regist&a=1  -> /signup?a=1
/oldpage?f=confirm     -> /signup?t=confirm
/oldpage?f=confirm&a=1 -> /signup?t=confirm&a=1
```

but my redirect result in nginx (v1.12.2) is

```
/oldpage?f=regist      -> /signup?f=regist
/oldpage?f=regist&a=1  -> Not Found
/oldpage?f=confirm     -> /signup?t=confirm?f=confirm
/oldpage?f=confirm&a=1 -> Not Found
```

I set nginx.conf as,

```
map $request_uri $rewrite_uri {
    include conf.d/redirect.map;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($rewrite_uri) {
        rewrite ^ $rewrite_uri redirect;
    }
}
```

and redirect.map is

```
/oldpage?f=regist /signup;
/oldpage?f=confirm /signup?t=confirm;
```

It would be really appreciated if you could give me some advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `a=1` parameter represents any other parameters, and you do not wish to add those combinations to the map file, you should change the syntax of your map file to use regular expressions.

The regular expressions in the `map` block can create named captures which can be used later in the configuration. In the example below, the `$prefix` and `$suffix` variables are named captures from the `map` block.

The example below has some caveats - because the `$prefix` and `$suffix` values may be empty, the generated URIs may contain a trailing `?` or `&` - which should not affect the overall semantics.

All of the regular expressions and the mapped values have a common pattern to capture optional parameters and append them to the resulting value.

```
map $request_uri $new {
    default 0;
    ~*^/oldpage\?(?<prefix>.*&)?f=regist(&(?<suffix>.*))?$   /signup?;
    ~*^/oldpage\?(?<prefix>.*&)?f=confirm(&(?<suffix>.*))?$  /signup?t=confirm&;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($new) {
        return 301 $new$prefix$suffix;
    }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.